# IDE independent Android interface designer

Tags: java, android

IDEs such as Eclipse or Android studio have built-in interface designers.

I prefer work with Emacs. Emacs works well for me but, I need a resource viewer that will allow me to check how my xml resources will look when they're viewed.

Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would consider [Droid Draw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/droiddraw.mirror/).